# Subsetting across multiple columns with empty cells

Tags: r, multiple-columns, subset

I have a large data set where each row may have one cell with text while the remaining are empty. Is there a way to subset those rows with text in only a given column while the remaining are empty?

I know I can use e.g. `tmp[tmp$A!="" & tmp$B=="" & tmp$C=="" & tmp$D=="",]`, but as I have approx. 30 columns where I would like to run this for each column this would be rather tedious . I have tried the following, but it doesn't behave as expected.

```
tmp=data.frame(A=c("a","","","",""),
            B=c("","b","","",""),
            C=c("","","c","",""),
                D=c("","","","D",""))
#Attempting subsetting across multiple columns with tmp[,2:3]
tmp[tmp[,1]!="" & tmp[,2:3]=="",]
      A    B    C    D
1     a               
NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>

#But it results in creating rows with na
tmp[tmp[,1]!="" & tmp[,2:4]=="",]
        A    B    C    D
1       a               
NA   <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
NA.1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Where I would like to only end up with:

```
    A    B    C    D
 1       a
```

Which would then be used in an `ifelse()`, so that if there is only cell in column A with text, give column E text A, if only text in column B give column E text B

```
    A    B    C    D    E
    a                   A
         b              B
              c         C
                   d    D
```

Suggestions?

Comment: take a look at `complete.cases`.

Comment: @Justin, can't see how that would help in my case.

Comment: @Henrik, good suggestion, but it doesn't apply for my case. I elaborated my question to make it more understandable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample data frame character vectors are converted to factors, so you can remove the default behavior of R by using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your sample data frame

```
 tmp=data.frame(A=c("a","","","",""),
                    B=c("","b","","",""),
                    C=c("","","c","",""),
                    D=c("","","","D",""),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then you can get what you expect:

```
kk<-tmp[tmp[,1]!="",]
> kk
  A B C D
1 a   

ll<-tmp[tmp[,2]!="",]
> ll
  A B C D
2   b 


 tmp[1:4,"E"]<-names(is.na(c(tmp)))
 tmp
  A B C D    E
1 a          A
2   b        B
3     c      C
4       D    D
5         <NA>

na.omit(tmp)
  A B C D E
1 a       A
2   b     B
3     c   C
4       D D
```

......................................................................
Original comments:

Using `str(tmp)`

```
 str(tmp)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 2 levels "","a": 2 1 1 1 1
 $ B: Factor w/ 2 levels "","b": 1 2 1 1 1
 $ C: Factor w/ 2 levels "","c": 1 1 2 1 1
 $ D: Factor w/ 2 levels "","D": 1 1 1 2 1
```

So,

```
levels(tmp[,1])
[1] ""  "a"
```

So, you need to use `levels(tmp[,1]))==""`

................................................................

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but the help was much appreciated :)

Comment: Mmmh..I can't seem to make this work on a dataframe that is not quadratic, i.e. it has more rows than columns.

Comment: Your sample data has 5 rows and 4 columns. The code works here and probably it should work in your real data.

Comment: My frame is 82 820 rows by 22 columns (it looks nasty, but I didn't make it :P), if interested its available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrad2ogyl4smeyp/tmp_output.csv

Comment: You need to try first with 50 rows and 22 cols. If that works, I don't think there will be problem

Comment: With the following subset `tmp=df[1:50,]`, I get the message:
`tmp[1:50,"E"]<-names(is.na(c(tmp)))    
Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, 1:50, "E", value = c("Rike", "Underrike",  : 
  replacement has 22 rows, data has 50`

Comment: `tmp[1:4,"E"]` is used because first 4 rows have a,b,c,d as data and not just used as a subset. Try updating the question with 50 rows and 10 cols, if its okay.